# Installing boost on macos

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake

I am trying to create a simple example using the boost library. I can successfully use CMake for the initial setup and it finds boost.

[image]

using the following code in CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(edge_detector)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(edge_detector main.cpp)
target_include_directories(edge_detector PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
target_link_libraries(edge_detector ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

However when I try to build the project using make or CMake --build . boost is not found and I am met with this error:

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing, I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Welcome on SO please [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438)

Answer (score 3):

Your include directive must include a file not a directory.
Replace

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string>
```

with

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, was stuck for a day on this haha